# Recognizing text from image using google vision, doesn't work

Tags: android, text-extraction, google-vision

screenshot for the App click on the following caption:
[image: Android App, should appear extracted messages on the text view on the main activity]

I'm using this dependence with Nexus6 API 31 'implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.3'

this is the code for the android app

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.view.View;


import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.vision.Frame;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextBlock;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.text.TextRecognizer;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textView;
    private EditText editText;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }

    public void buttonReadText(View view){
        try {
            String stringFileName = "/storage/emulated/0/Download/" + editText.getText().toString();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(stringFileName);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            TextRecognizer textRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(this).build();
            Frame frameImage = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build();


            SparseArray<TextBlock> textBlockSparseArray = textRecognizer.detect(frameImage);
            String stringImageText = "";
            for (int i = 0; i<textBlockSparseArray.size();i++){
                TextBlock textBlock = textBlockSparseArray.get(textBlockSparseArray.keyAt(i));


                stringImageText = stringImageText + " " + textBlock.getValue();
                System.out.println(stringImageText);
            }
            textView.setText(stringImageText);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            textView.setText("Failed");
        }
    }
}
```

I expect extracted text from the image will appear on the Main activity on the text view.

Comment: What isn't working?  Where is the error?  Is there an exception being thrown?  Also, the google vision SDK is deprecated and is replaced by MLKit